# Is it possible to achieve a table like implementation where columns would expand on whitespace and also show ellipses when text would overflow?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have been trying for 3 days to achieve the table design our UX designer wants, to no success.

I need to create a table with N columns, where first N-1 columns are aligned to the left of the screen, and the last column is aligned to the right. Each column should take white space based on the largest element in it's rows. Between columns there should be a 24px spacing at all times. When the screen gets smaller and there is no more white space available in the table, the columns should have it's text overflow displayed as ellipses. The table should not overflow just become smaller and smaller and with it's content hidden by ellipses.

I have tried all the answers I could find while googling, even attempted some chat gpt suggestions, but nothing works completely.

Attempted to do the implementation using table but with table-layout fixed my text does not expand to take the available white space.
With table layout auto text expand to the available space but does not show ellipses when text overflows, it just hides the table from right to left. (Tried wrapping the content with width: 0 min-width: 100% in a td parent with 100% width but did not work)

Attempted to do the implementation using grid-template-columns but when narrowing the screen it eats up space from left to right, instead of eating it from the available space that is between N-1 column and N column.

My final result needs to look something like this on larger screen:

```
|Column A  | |Column B| |Column C          |                                              |Column D|
|----------| |--------| |------------------| -------------------------------------------- |--------|
| Cell 1234| |Cell 2  | |Cell 5            |                                              |Cell 6  | 
| Cell 3   | |Cell 4  | |Cell 5555555555555|                                              |Cell 6  |
```

Like this on intermediate screen:

```
|Column A  | |Column B| |Column C          |     |Column D|
|----------| |--------| |------------------| --- |--------|
| Cell 1234| |Cell 2  | |Cell 5            |     |Cell 6  | 
| Cell 3   | |Cell 4  | |Cell 5555555555555|     |Cell 6  |
```

And like this on small screen:

```
|Column A  | |Column B| |Column C | |Column D|
|----------| |--------| |---------| |--------|
| Cell 1234| |Cell 2  | |Cell 5   | |Cell 6  | 
| Cell 3   | |Cell 4  | |Cell 5...| |Cell 6  |
```

And even smaller:

```
|Column A | |Column B| |Column C | |Column D|
|---------| |--------| |---------| |--------|
| Cell 1..| |Cell 2  | |Cell 5   | |Cell 6  | 
| Cell 3  | |Cell 4  | |Cell 5...| |Cell 6  |
```

Is this behavior even achievable ?

Answer (score 0):

I've "perhaps" a solution with grid.

It's playing with the real grid positioning of elements and the minmax.

I'm not sure it can answer exactly to your question, but it can give you a good track.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, auto) minmax(50px, auto) minmax(50px, auto) minmax(24px, 1fr) minmax(50px, auto);
  gap: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#grid>div {
  min-height: 100px;
}

#grid>div span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(134, 224, 208, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  background-color: rgba(152, 79, 175, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(44, 184, 77, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div4 {
  grid-area: 1 / 5 / 2 / 6;
  background-color: rgba(196, 154, 3, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div5 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(82, 17, 37, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div6 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  background-color: rgba(249, 154, 182, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div7 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(144, 252, 111, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div8 {
  grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 6;
  background-color: rgba(254, 14, 250, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div9 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(224, 23, 19, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div10 {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
  background-color: rgba(75, 240, 154, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div11 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(249, 8, 188, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

#div12 {
  grid-area: 3 / 5 / 4 / 6;
  background-color: rgba(155, 205, 226, 0.5);
  justify-self: start;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #grid {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(50px, auto) minmax(50px, auto) minmax(50px, auto) minmax(24px, 24px) minmax(50px, auto);
  }
  #grid>div {
    justify-self: stretch;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="div1"><span>div1div1div1div1</span></div>
  <div id="div2"><span>div2div2div2div2</span></div>
  <div id="div3"><span>div3div3div3div3</span></div>
  <div id="div4"><span>div4div4div4div4</span></div>
  <div id="div5"><span>div5div5div5div5</span></div>
  <div id="div6"><span>div6div6div6div6</span></div>
  <div id="div7"><span>div7div7div7div7</span></div>
  <div id="div8"><span>div8div8div8div8</span></div>
  <div id="div9"><span>div9div9div9div9</span></div>
  <div id="div10"><span>div10div10div10div10</span></div>
  <div id="div11"><span>div11div11div11div11</span></div>
  <div id="div12"><span>div12div12div12div12</span></div>
</div>
```

try "small screen" to see it. Here small is defined at 768px, which in fact is intermediate. You can play with the 4th col definition